# How do I get a default layout to use different stylesheets based on device resolution?

Tags: java, android, layout, styles

So this application I'm working on has a ton of activities in it, and for each activity, there's 5 layouts (default, sw650dp, sw730dp, sw800dp, sw800dp-h1050dp) each with their own attributes and values that are assigned using the styles.xml file.

What I want to do is have each activity run off of a single default layout, and load the proper styles.xml based on the resolution of the device.

***Example: Activity "activity_user" has a default layout, with elements like text and buttons being assigned styles (@style/textStyle and @style/buttonStyle). In the @res/values/styles directory, there are 5 styles.xml files all at different resolutions, and they all have a style named "textStyle" and "buttonStyle". If the app is running on a device at sw800dp, then the "textStyle" and "buttonStyle" styles are pulled from the sw800dp version of the styles.xml file.***

***Image of Example:***

[image]

Since Android knows which layout to pick based on the device's resolution, I assumed that adding a styles.xml for each resolution and then deleting the related resolution's layout would work as long as the name of the style is the same across all styles.xml files. However, it seems to only take whatever a named style has in place for the default styles.xml and all the other resolutions are ignored.

***Example: Default layout assigns some text the "BodyButtonStyle" style (@style/BodyButtonStyle). In the default styles.xml the text is white, but in the sw800dp version, the text is orange. However, when I load up the app on an sw800dp device, the text is white.***

Both the default styles.xml and the sw800dp styles.xml have the style declared like this -

Default:

```
<style name="BodyButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">280dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/someFont</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rectangle_shape_button</item>
     <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

sw800dp:

```
<style name="BodyButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">400dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/someFont</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPink</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">45sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rectangle_shape_button</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf">@+id/guideline_bottom</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintHorizontal_bias">0.5</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

How would I get the default layout to load the proper styles.xml file according to the resolution, as it seems to do automatically when there are multiple resolutions for the layout?

Comment: Do you have anything for `BodyButtonStyle` in the `sw800dp-h1050dp` style resource?

Comment: @CommonsWare I do have similar values placed in the sw800dp-h1050dp range.